# javascript/jquery - dynamically add data by id to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, dynamic, resume

Attempting to build a resume creator as a project for codeacademy.

I'm using a button to "save" the user's input to an array so it can later be appended into the resume.

However, I'm failing at getting the data to "save" to the array. I've looked at similar questions here on stackoverflow and I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong.

#### here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2EX6/3/)

specific code block I'm having trouble with:

```
$('#experiencesave').click(function(){
for (var i = 0; i < jobs; i++){
jobtitle.push = $('#jobtitle'+i).val();
}
$('#morejobs').append(jobtitle);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, [`.push` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is a function which has to be called:

```
jobtitle.push($('#jobtitle'+i).val());
```

---

As an alternative solution, instead of using a `for` loop, you might want to use [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to collect the values:

```
var jobtitle = $('input[id^=jobtitle]').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

I don't see a reason to give each of those input elements an ID though. Just give them a class. That makes it a bit easier to bulk-process them later. E.g. the selector could then just be `$('input.jobtitle')`.

Comment: thank you. i cant believe i forgot to call .push(), using your map function instead because it worked haha. i don't understand how .map() works...could you explain it to me or point me to a tutorial that is beginner oriented?

Comment: The `map` comes from functional programming. You give it a list of values and *map* (convert) it to a list of different values. How the values are converted is defined by a function (which is passed to the `map` function as argument). In this answer, we have a list of elements (`$('input[id^=jobtitle]')`) and map each element to the value of its `.value` property (`function() { return this.value; }`). You can also have a look at Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) or the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/map/.

Comment: okay sorry im still learning but it sounds like we go through a set of data - apply a function to each piece of data and then create a new set of data with the applied function. couple things I don't understand...in the code above you put `'input[id^=jobtitle]` are we mapping every input with the id jobtitle? what does the caret (^) mean in that code?

Comment: `[...^=...]` is the *attribute-starts-with* selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/. Here is a list of all selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/. And yes, it selects every input element with an ID that starts with `jobtitle`. Your understanding of the map function seems to be correct as well.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. I was looking and all I could find was ^ being an XOR logic operator which made no sense.